BULK insert not dealing with accented characters
I apologise for raising a question that's been asked in so many forms before but I'm tearing my hair out...
I am using BULK INSERT to load what I firmly believe to be (and Notepad++ reports to be) a UTF-8 file and it contains many EU accented characters which are being lost and shown typically as 2 characters, the first of which is often ASCII 43 (typically a + sign but does not display as that). I have also done an octal dump of the file and, while "standard" characters occupy one byte, the accented ones occupy 2 bytes which I assume is UTF-8. Rows are terminated with LF, no CR.
If I import the file using SSMS for the same database, it is pulled into a table with correct accents showing but not with BULK INSERT.
I have tried using CODEPAGE = 'RAW' and 'ACP' to no avail - it imports the data but accents are lost. I have also tried DATAFILETYPE ='widechar' and 'widenative' without success. Example:
    BULK INSERT #Tmp1 FROM 'Fred.csv' 
      WITH (FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
            ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a' , CODEPAGE = 'ACP' );

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Yes it does thank you. In fact I'd just found it myself. If I used this forum more often I'd have found your comment earlier. I kept viewing the page and looking for possible answers and missed the comment. Also no email noification which I should investigate. Thanks again. I will add an answer too.

As JosefZ pointed out in his comment (and as I independently found myself because of my complete failure to notice that comment) the answer is in his link: How to write UTF-8 characters using bulk insert in SQL Server?
In short, use CODEPAGE = 65001 in the BULK INSERT statement.
Thanks again.
